# The line coming out of the XY turn is much smaller than the other elements on the map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

Firstly, I have two tables, one is for investment companies and the other is for investment projects, and they both have longitude and latitude information. I want to see their connections on the map and change the thickness of the connection based on the investment amount. I have created the connections by matching the attributes of the tables.

However, I encountered a problem when using the XY to Line tool. The resulting lines are almost invisible on the map at a scale of 1:500, but my map requires them to be visible at a scale of around 1:8000000.

As for the specific settings, my study area is in East Asia, where X corresponds to longitude and Y corresponds to latitude. I have tried all the line types provided by ArcGIS, but the result is still very thin lines.I am certain that the projection of the lines and other map elements is consistent.

What could be the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Are you using the ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap application of the ArcGIS Desktop product?

Comment: ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.I tried ArcGIS Pro too,the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved. In the last step of the XY to line conversion, the coordinate system should be selected as the geographic coordinate system, and then the projection tool should be used to convert to the desired projection. If you select the final desired projection directly you will have this problem.